# Dbnull in VB.NET Stored procedure OUT Parameter

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures, error-handling

The problem I have is that the stored procedure isn't bringing me the result in my VB.NET side. When I test my stored procedure in the Mysql Database it works perfect. So I assume that is the VB.NET side. I tried alot of methods that I saw on web, and they are very similar of the code I putting below. So tell me what I am doing wrong? I how can evaluate what is happening when I connect to DB that I can't receive any answer in my OUT PARAMETER.

```
Try
    conexion.Open()
    command.Connection = conexion
    command.CommandText = "DUA_ENCABEZADO_TRAERPAISORIGEN"
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_DUA", CInt(TxtCodDUA.Text))
    command.Parameters("@COD_DUA").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input               
    command.Parameters.Add("@CODIGO_PAIS", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()


    XML_PaisOrigen = command.Parameters(1).Value.ToString   

    conexion.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message & vbCrLf & "Error al ejecutar << " & ex.Message,MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error Popup")

End Try
```

'XML_PaisOrigen is a String

This is my Mysql SP:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `DUA_ENCABEZADO_TRAERPAISORIGEN`(
     IN COD_DUA INT,
     OUT CODIGO_PAIS VARCHAR(2))
```

This is my Call of the SP and works in MYSQL side:

```
SET @COD_DUA =1;
CALL DUA_ENCABEZADO_TRAERPAISORIGEN(@COD_DUA,@CODIGO_PAIS);
SELECT @CODIGO_PAIS;
```

Comment: Did u try this way command.Parameters("@CODIGO_PAIS").Value.ToString();

Comment: Yes, I tried. Still brings me DBnull on the result.

Comment: I assume you have the MySql installer / a connector installed to access MySql DB ?

Comment: Yes sir, Im connected to make INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,SELECT. In all my application and works perfect. But returning to my problem is the STORED PROCEDURE, specific.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution. It's really strange how SP works sometimes. First of all Download this program. Is my savor http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html

```
     FETCH cur_paisorigen INTO Var2;
             IF Var2 = Var1 then                    
                  If v_finished = 1 then
                     -- SET Var_Result = Var2;  It WAS HERE             
                      leave cur_loop;
                   SET Var_Result = Var2;   -- NEXT I TRIED HERE AND IT WORK
                 End If;
              else
                 SET Var_Result = 216;
                 leave cur_loop;
               End If;
```

This SET Var_Result;

Make sure your set OUT PUT variable goes clean. I had to debug my SP. To figure out. Because when I execute the SP in MYSQL Workbench it worked perfect. But When I debug with this program my OUT variable it came NULL. So make sure to SET your OUT variable clean.

Another thing I learn today.   SET your variable OUT OF THE LOOP NOT IN THE LOOP.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is put the parameters into a variable so it is easier to work with.

```
    Try
        conexion.Open()
        command.Connection = conexion
        command.CommandText = "DUA_ENCABEZADO_TRAERPAISORIGEN"
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        dim p1 as sqlParameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_DUA", CInt(TxtCodDUA.Text))
        p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input               
        dim p2 as sqlParameter = command.Parameters.Add("@CODIGO_PAIS", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 2)
        p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()


       XML_PaisOrigen = p.Value.ToString   

       conexion.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message & vbCrLf & "Error al ejecutar << " & ex.Message,MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error Popup")

    End Try
```

Comment: Tried this way, same result. NO RESULT back from SP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the if operator and IsDBNull() to avoid your error. I assume that you want an empty string, if the stored procedure returns a NULL value:

```
XML_PaisOrigen = If(IsDBNull(command.Parameters(1).Value), "", command.Parameters(1).Value.ToString)
```